# pythonのwith文がとることのできる要素について

Tags: python

何が問題なのかわかっていないので適切な質問ができないのですが，以下のようなwith文を使って書かれたコードの構造がわかりません．
以下は疑似コードです．

```
import gzip
import codecs

with codecs.getreader('utf-8')(gzip.open(u'inputfile.gz', 'r')) as f:
    for line in f:
        some processes
```

（この例は[言語処理100本ノック](http://www.cl.ecei.tohoku.ac.jp/nlp100/)の問題20を念頭に置いています）
このwith文において，gzip.open()はcodecs.getreader()とどういう関係にあるのでしょうか？
つまり，gzip.open()はcodecsのメソッドではないし，.getreaderのスコープにも入っていませんので，おそらくwith文の要素のひとつになっているのだと思うのですが，どういう要素かわかりません．with文はこのように並列的にいくつも要素（項？）をとることができるのだとして，それらはどういう関係にあるのでしょうか？

Comment: `with codecs.getreader('utf-8')(gzip.open(u'inputfile.gz', 'r')) as f:` は、`f = codecs.getreader('utf-8').__enter__(gzip.open(u'inputfile.gz', 'r'))` と等価です。

Comment: ありがとうございます．勉強が足りず，.__enter__()がなんなのかわからずにおりますが，with文が直接関係しているわけではないということかと思います．withは，asに続く変数にwithのあとの処理の結果を渡すだけ（終わったら勝手に閉じる）で，変数に=で代入しても同じことだということかと理解しました．

Answer (score 1):

例外を気にしなければ

```
f = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(gzip.open(u'inputfile.gz', 'r'))
for line in f:
    some processes
f.close()
```

と書けるので、`with`は関係ありません。

[Pythonのドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/library/codecs.html#codecs.getreader)を参照すると

> codecs.getreader(encoding) 与えられたエンコーディングに対する codec を検索し、StreamReader クラスまたはファクトリ関数を返します。

とあるので、`codecs.getreader`の返す値は、そのまま関数として呼び出すことができます。したがって最初の行は、更に

```
factory = codecs.getreader('utf-8')
gzippeddata = gzip.open(u'inputfile.gz', 'r')
f = factory(gzippeddata)
```

と書けます。つまり`codecs.getreader('utf-8')(gzip.open(u'inputfile.gz', 'r'))`は連続関数呼び出しなのです。

一般的に`f()()`のような構文は、連続で関数を呼び出していることが多いです。

Comment: わかりました！
codecs.getreader()の返す値は関数である，つまりこの部分が関数になっていて，それに続く()にはその関数の引数が入り，その引数としてgzip.open()がとられているということですね．
構造が見えました．ありがとうございました．

Comment: with文の問題ではないということもわかりました．with文のドキュメントには関連する記述がなかったのですが，関係なかったということで納得しました．

Answer (score 0):

こういうことではないでしょうか。

```
import gzip
import codecs

myreader =  codecs.getreader('utf-8')
with myreader(gzip.open(u'inputfile.gz', 'r')) as f:
    for line in f:
        some processes
```

Comment: ありがとうございます．やはりcodecs.getreader()が関数を返していて，それを一旦変数に受けると，お書きいただいたように分けて書くことができるということですね．gzip.openが入っている()がなんなのかわからなかったのですが，すっきり理解できました．